# Define a function to repeat a word

Tags: python, function, repeat

I'm trying to do a task from a tutorial which is to define a function that will repeat an inputted word an inputted number of times, so far I have:

```
s = raw_input("Enter a word:")
n = input("Enter a number:")

def repeat_this(s, n):
    print s * n
```

However s and n aren't defined locally in repeat_this, but I couldn't get the user input to work when I defined s and n inside the function, could anyone provide any tips of how to get this to work?

N.B. When I run the file containing this it accepts input for s and n, but then leaves a blank line and starts a new empty line, where repeat-this is not defined.

Comment: Where are you calling the function/method - repeat_this(s, n) and passing the values?
you need to call the function for it to print the output.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling the function. Add this to the end of the script:

```
repeat_this(s, n)
```

Also, your inputs should both be `raw_input()` (coerce the number to an integer using `int()` rather than dangerously allowing Python to parse it) and should probably go below the function definition (it'll work either way, but it's better style to put all the script stuff together below your function and global variable definitions). Putting it all together:

```
def repeat_this(s, n):
    print s * n

s = raw_input("Enter a word:")
n = int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))
repeat_this(s, n)
```

Comment: @kindall Good point well made, I wouldn't want someone entering a float now would I haha, thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: @RayToal There are no winners, and I'll be honest I read your's first and was about to comment back when you deleted the post!

Comment: Not only could someone enter a float, but they could enter a list, a dict, a set, `__import__("sys").exit(1)` (thereby exiting the whole Python interpreter) or any other legal Python expression, many of which can do things you might not want done.

Comment: @Kindall good point, unfortunately at the moment I can only program against what I know, and I don't know how to enter a dict, set or list yet, but I have modified it to restrict the input, thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @GeorgeBurrows True about the timing, however your answer was _better_ anyway, as it included the suggestion to use `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the embedded print, your `repeat_this()` function is effectively the multiply operator, which can be used as a function on it's own:

```
from operator import mul

s = raw_input("Enter a word:")
n = input("Enter a number:")

print mul(s, n)
```